# Int switch error when inject code generator with switch case in java code

Tags: android, dex, java-bytecode-asm, android-r8

> Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
> at com.android.tools.r8.ir.code.IntSwitch.valid(IntSwitch.java:67)
> at com.android.tools.r8.ir.code.IntSwitch.(IntSwitch.java:35)
> at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRBuilder.createSwitch(IRBuilder.java:1922)
> at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRBuilder.addSwitch(IRBuilder.java:1886)
> at com.android.tools.r8.cf.code.CfSwitch.buildIR(CfSwitch.java:101)
> at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.CfSourceCode.build(CfSourceCode.java:581)
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.

java sample

```
 public IFactory getInjectMap(String var1) {
          byte var2 = -1;
          switch(var1.hashCode()) {
          case 2011670744:
             if (var1.equals("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")) {
                var2 = 0;
             }
             break;
          case -1047643106:
             if (var1.equals("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")) {
                var2 = 1;
             }
             break;
          }
    
          switch(var2) {
          case 0:
             var2 = (byte)(new xxxxFactory());
             break;
          case 1:
             var2 = (byte)(new xxxxFactory());
             break;
          default:
             var2 = (byte)null;
          }
    
          return var2;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti i just fix it thanks

Comment: The decompiler you’ve used seems to be fundamentally flawed, as it does not recognize that the variable initialized in the second `switch` must have a different type than the variable used in the first and even inserts nonsensical casts from reference types to `byte` based on this wrong assumption. Besides that, this seems to be a switch over strings, not recognized by the decompiler. The conclusion is that you should show the actual bytecode, rather than the result of this decompiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [assertion error you hit](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/6caaf88dfcb2e5c53803d11a86cb4f634cb75468/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/ir/code/IntSwitch.java#67) is validating that the values in the `lookupswitch` instruction is ordered, as [mandated by the JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.lookupswitch). This indicate that the generated bytecode is not following the specification. Does this code run on the JVM?

This is also reported as https://issuetracker.google.com/200284898#comment6.